# Run Sequelize raw query for each result of another sequelize query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, q, bluebird, async.js

i am using sequelize.js in node app to fetch data from a query and then run another sequelize raw query for each result element. but dude to callbacks i am not getting results.

my code:

```
var raw_query1 = "select id,name,has_results from users";
sequelize.query(raw_query1).then(function(results) {

  var outputArray = []; // to store use results with additional results 

  for(i=0;i<results.length;i++){
   outputArray[i].name = results[i].name;

   var raw_query2 = "select * from meta where user_id = "+resulsts[i].id;

    sequelize.query(raw_query2).then(function(meta_results) {
      outputArray[i].meta = meta_results;
    }


  }

  return res.json(outputArray); //Returning parsed results

});
```

i think we need to use promise here but i am a newbie from php and dont know how to proceed thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `bluebird.map`.

```
var raw_query1 = "select id,name,has_results from users";
sequelize.query(raw_query1).then(function(results) {

  return bluebird.map(results, function(user){
    var raw_query2 = "select * from meta where user_id = "+user.id;
    return sequelize.query(raw_query2)
  })
    .then(function(metas){
      return res.json(metas);
    });
});
```